# Descriptions of m o D for \NewDocumentCommand

Tags: programming, documentation

Where can I find documentation for `m`, `o` ,and `D` for `\NewDocumentCommand` as I cannot find them in `interface3.pdf`.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\newconject}{momoD(){black}}
```

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand` and its family of related commands can be found documented in [`xparse`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf).

Comment: Cannot understand the `D(){black}` part from the documentation.

Comment: I see `D⟨token1⟩⟨token2⟩{⟨default⟩}`.  What does that mean ? What are `⟨token1⟩` and `⟨token2⟩` ?

Comment: @Veak `(token1)` and `(token2)` are the delimiters of the optional argument. A `token` is usually a single character. `(default)` is the default value.

Comment: What are the takens for the case of `D(){black}` ?  Can you provide examples using  `\NewDocumentCommand` with such tokens ?

Comment: You define a command with a (final) optional argument (#5) surrounded by `(` and `)`. If the argument isn't provided, `#5` will be assigned the default value `black`. `m` is a mandatory argument, surrounded by braces (a short one, no more than one paragraph) and `o` is an optional argument surrounded by `[` `]` (basically a shortcut for `d[]`).

Comment: The concept of token is quite basic in TeX; it's described in several places (the main doc is "the TeXbook" by Knuth). Try for example "Tex by topic" https://texdoc.org/serve/texbytopic/0

Comment: It means a fifth optional argument that can be defaulted to `black`.  But how could one use the fifth argument exactly ?

Answer (score 8):

`\NewDocumentCommand`, etc., form part of the document interface for LaTeX, and so are useful to general documented authors as well as programmers. As such, they are documented in `usrguide` (available using `texdoc usrguide` on a system with LaTeX installed). As noted in comments, historically these ideas were developed in a separate package called `xparse`, and thus `texdoc xparse` will provide similar information: `xparse` still exists as some ideas were *not* carried forward to core LaTeX, and so need to be retained as deprecated material.

Briefly, `\NewDocumentCommand` takes three arguments

- The name of a command to define, e.g, `\foo`
- The *argument specification*, e.g. `som`
- The replacement text, e.g. `Text using #2 and #3`

Of these, the most complex is the argument specification ('arg spec'). The arg spec lists what arguments our new command will take. Each type of argument is given a letter: some of these letters also need to be followed by additional info. The most common arg types are

- `m` - A standard mandatory argument
- `o` - An optional argument which if not given returns a special marker
- `O{<default>}`  - An optional argument which returns `<default>` if not given
- `s` - An optional star
- `D<t1><t2>{<default>}` - a generalisation of `O{<default>}` in which `<t1>` and `<t2>` delimit the optional argument, e.g. `D(){black}` would be an optional argument delimited by `()` which if not given would supply `black` to the command

In the replacement text, the values grabbed as arguments are represented by `#1`, etc. in order, so for example

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand{\newconject}{m o m o D(){black}}
```

would have

- `#1` the first mandatory argument
- `#2` the first optional argument inside `[]`
- `#3` the second mandatory argument
- `#4` the second optional argument inside `[]`
- `#5` The final optional argument inside `()`